# WooCommerce related product - only show from primary category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have products in multiply categories

e.g. `"All lamps"`, `"Ceiling lamps"` and `"Black lamps"`.

`"Black lamps"` is the primary category (using Yoast SEO for making primary category).

My problem is that related products show products from all selected categories.

Is it possible to have related products only show from the primary category?

Comment: I found the solution here => https://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/snippets/yoast-seo-primary-category-related-products/ I added the script as a global script with a snippet plugin and works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Leonardo for linking to solution here https://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/snippets/yoast-seo-primary-category-related-products/

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). Please add a solution.